# php+iis7 not able to send email?

Tags: php, iis-7, amazon-ec2

I m not able to send email through php code using iis7 server.Here is the warning that i m getting from server.

```
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550-(ip-0AD2EFB5) [ip]:50942 is currently not permitted to relay 550 through this server. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\email\sendemail.php on line 17

and the 17th line is mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

can anybody help me solve this issue?

Comment: create SMTP server on IIS and allow from 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: I have already installed SMTP server on amazon server.

Comment: then  you have to modify in `php.ini` SMTP to sent threw 127.0.0.1

Comment: I have entered the smtp server,email address ,port,authentication settings(email and password) to SMTP server and email and smtp server and port to php.ini

Answer (score 1):

This issue has nothing to do with PHP nor IIS7, but with the SMTP policy.

The SMTP server in your network (or ISP/hosting) doesn't allow injection of mail from outside their network. You have to either connect to your SMTP from inside the ISP's network, or you some sort of authentication that is allowed to access the SMTP server.

This policy was made so that the SMTP won't be used by malicious user to inject spam mail (which is called 'open relay').

EDIT:
Just noticed your amazon-ec2 tag, it seems like you are running in Amazon AWS cloud?
Probably what you need is [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/)